# change the data in single fragment using the swipeable tablayout

Tags: java, android, json, android-viewpager

I want to change data when I swipe a `ViewPager` in `Fragment`.

Data of `Tabview` comes from `JSON`. It gives `id` and according to that id, data will be retrieved.
But when `mainActivity` is loaded it gives first two position simultaneously.

**ActivityMain.java**

```
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            String serverUrl = DataService.category;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            System.out.println("the response text is " + responseText);
            response_text = new JSONObject(responseText);
            JSONArray jarray=response_text.getJSONArray("posts");
            for(int k=0;k<jarray.length();k++)
            {
                JSONObject jk=jarray.getJSONObject(k);
                adapter.addFragment(new TopNewsFragment(),jk.getString("categoryName"),jk.getString("c_id"));
                arraylist.add(jk.getString("c_id"));
            }
            fetchDate();
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is my `ViewPager Adapter` class.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title,String category)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("category_id",category);
        b.putString("title",title);
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Also it does not show first and last position.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should move that line under `fragment.setArguments`: mFragmentList.add(fragment); Also be aware the HttpClient is a deprecated class now, I guess you are targetting older APIs. Consider using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: thanks but i try problem remains same...

Comment: First and last position of what? The problem is a bit unclear. Is there some kind of error? Is your code for downloading data in the OnCreate method? Consider using another method for the download itself called for example downloadContent, put your HTTP request there and then just use downloadContent() in onCreate. The Pager adapter seems fine so could it be that the response is empty? I want to also expand on my previous comment, I suggest that you also look into a library making JSON tasks easier, like Volley or GSON. Seriously, they are nice and easier to understand than this I believe.

Comment: when i swipe a tab, if it is at first or last position it does not show its id.

Answer (score 0):

Use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

Check this link you may got answer : [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)